# asp.net to check character

Tags: asp.net

i have one text box ....if i type character how can i check it is characte in asp.net (application layer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking the text entered in a textbox, you might want to use the TextChanged event, which is triggered only after the textBox loses focus. You can hook it up either in javascript (client) or in code (server).

Another option is to have some validator to restrict the allowed characters. You might want to take a look at this article from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998267.aspx (How To: Use Regular Expressions to Constrain Input in ASP.NET).

Comment: Hmm, it seems you want to check if inputed text is character? In this case you can create regularExpression validator with \w regex.

Comment: in textchanged event i got ewwor if i type characcter(input string not in correct format)

Comment: Domnic, I need to see your code in order to understand the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into the .net validator controls for this. They provide a wide range of input validation facilities.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542.aspx